# Dual-Boot Win7 and Apple?

Tags: startup, windows

First off, I have no idea what Apple calls their OS. I only use their iOS devices and I tried to avoid their computer OS as best as possible, however, I'm getting started in developing iOS apps. I need to either run the Apple OS in a VM or set up dual-booting. I have a few questions though that hopefully can get answered.

1. Where can I purchase a license for Apple?
2. I've never set up dual-booting before, how do I go about doing so with Win7 as my current OS? (Ideally using a different HDD)
3. Is there anything I should know before going ahead?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/679896/what-are-the-technical-obstacles-that-doesnt-allow-osx-to-be-installed-in-a-pc. Anyway, the answer to your first question is that is not possible to purchase a license to OS X alone.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, you purchase a license for OS X by buying a Mac. It is licensed only for Apple hardware.

There is no other way to legitimately run it, either natively or in VM.

Running it on any other hardware would be against Apple's EULA & would also be off-topic for StackExchange.

Comment: The Mac can dual boot into Windows and OS X - but you need to buy a version of Windows the standard version is only an update of the one that comes on your PC

Comment: Well I'm not buying a Mac... I know for a fact that you can run OS X in a VM so if I can't dual-boot, I'm going to have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on my MacBook using Bootcamp which comes with the Mac OS. It allows me to partition off my hard drive into 2 and by holding down the Alt key when the Mac boots, it asks which OS I'd like to start. I can only use one at a time though. Recently I prefer to just run a VM of Windows from inside my Mac OS using VirtualBox.